# How to remove an anchor in a url with IIS rewrite module?

Tags: redirect, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have this url https://example.com/test/#/anchorpart1/anchorpart2 and I want to do a redirect to https://example.com/test2.

So far I created the following rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/test2" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
```

This will lead to the following result:

https://example.com/test2#/anchorpart1/anchorpart2

How can I remove "#/anchorpart1/anchorpart2" to have only "https://example.com/test2" maybe by using matching or condition rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portion of the URL after # (fragment) is never passed to the server as per HTTP specification, therefor, URL rewrite won't see it.

To solve this issue, you can deploy a static HTML page that will take care of redirecting requests like the example bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://example.com/test2">
</head> 
<body>

<script language="javascript">
     window.location.href = "https://example.com/test2"
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

By using the following solution, you will be able to escape the #(fragment) of the incoming request URL and redirect it.